# Busy Indicator not responding on XAML loading

Tags: wpf, busyindicator

I have a WPF application that has a complex UI with large data binding. I'm using WCF aynchronous calls to server for data. It will take around 4 seconds to get the data from server and for XAML binding it will take around 6 seconds. To get a user notification I have given a busy indicator that will run normally(progress is showing on the progress bar) untill the data reached on client side. When I assign that result to XAML, then  it(busy indicator) will become irresponsive(also the main window). Is it due to the single UI thread? Is it possible to show the busy indicator in a seperate thread (like background worker) inside the WCF asynchronous call? Or is any other good method to handle this scenario?

```cs
busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;    

ServiceAgentInstance.GetAll((s1, e1) =>    
    {    
        ObservableCollection<Model> collection = e1.Result;   
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;   
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
                        ServiceAgentInstance.GetAll((s1, e1) =>
                        {
                            ObservableCollection<Model> collection = e1.Result;
                            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
                        });

Comment: Edit the code into the question

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're making the WCF request on the UI thread which should be avoided. Try using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to make your request which should free up your UI thread to animate the busy indicator.